# How to improve Euler-Maruyama discretisation with analytical moments?

Tags: stochastic-processes, approximation

I'm trying to improve Euler-Maruyama discretisation by adding to it the analytical moments.
To try it I made a very simple example on the stochastic process $X(t) = W(t)^2$, where $W(t)$ is a standard Wiener process. Using Ito’s formula, I found the SDE $dX(t) = dt + 2 \sqrt{X(t)} dW(t) $ satisfied by
$X(t)$.

Using Euler-Maruyama’s method,I found the discretised version $$ \Delta X_i = \Delta t + 2 \sqrt{X_i  \Delta t} N_i$$
with $N_i$ random number extracted from a standard Normal.

Now, I would like to change this equation plugging in the analytical moments. I am a bit confused though. It seems to me that the analytical mean of the process can be found observing that $\mu_X = \Delta t$, therefore $d \mu_X = dt$. I have been told that the additional step is $\mu_X = X_0 + t$ but I don't exactly get why.

Additionally, I would like to find the analytical variance, but since $\sigma_X = \mu_{X^2}-\mu_X^2$ I would also need to find $\mu_{X^2}$.
I was thinking about squaring $X(t)$ and taking the mean but I'm a bit confused.

Thank to anyone who could provide some guidance.

**Update**

My professor's solution to find the variance is:

'By Ito's lemma
$$dX^2 = (2X + 4\frac{X}{2}2)dt + 2\sqrt{X}2XdW = 6Xdt +4X^{3/2}dW $$

thus we must solve
$$ d\mu_X^2 = 6\mu_X dt = 6 (X_0+t)dt $$

therefore

$$ \mu_X^2 = X_0^2 + 6 X_0 +3 t^2$$

then you find the variance with the above formula'

I have no idea what he's doing with Ito's lemma

Comment: I don't really understand: you already have the correct first moment. Are you now trying to ensure that the second moment of your discretized process agrees with that of the true process? The second moment is $E[W(t)^4]$ which is $3t^4$. Can you determine the second moment of your process? (I do not claim that this is easy!)

Comment: @Ian Yes the first moment is fine, but I don't quite get where it comes from.
See the update for the variance. It's not a matter of finding the solution, I'm trying to understand what's going on.

Comment: Oh, I see, your professor is using the Ito formula to find an SDE for $X^2$ from the SDE for $X$. You could also have found an SDE for $W^4$ directly: $d[W^4]=4W^3 dW + \frac{1}{2} 12 W^2 dt=4W^3 dW + 6 W^2 dt$. Since the expected value of an Ito integral is zero, $\frac{d}{dt}[E[W^4]]=6E[W^2]=6[X_0+t]$.$

Comment: @Ian thanks, that was helpful. One last super basic question but I somehow can't get it. How do you get $\mu_X = X_0 + t$?

Comment: Same thing, $dX=1dt+...dW$ so $\frac{d}{dt}E[X]=1$.

Comment: @Ian cool, that makes sense. Thank you

Comment: Also sorry, I made an error earlier, $E[W(t)^4]=3t^2$, not $3t^4$.